# Functions in Azure Data Factory Pipeline debugging Internal Server Error

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I followed exactly the ADF Azure Functions Tutorial at Microsoft Website and when I'm debugging my azure Function, I'm getting after debugging

```
{
    "errorCode": "3608",
    "message": "Call to provided Azure function '' failed with status-'InternalServerError' and message - 'Invoking Azure function failed with HttpStatusCode - InternalServerError.'.",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "azuretestFunction",
    "details": []
}
```

Usually when the '*Function Name*' is wrong, you'll get a '**Not Found**', but if function name is correct, I got a '**Internal Server Error**'.

On postman azure function works gorgeous.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1):

its resolved, it was my mystake --> Got a internal server error cause of missing body parameter. So Internal SErver Error could mean, anything is going wrong with your own code.