# Azure Function error on ADF - 3608 Error - Call to provided Azure function 'orchestrators/MyOrchestrator' failed with status-'InternalServerError'

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-durable-functions

I have Azure Durable Function (Python) developed in VS Code. I using Azurite as storage. Function works fine locally.

However I get strange error when deployed to Azure Functions (3.0) and calling from Azure Data Factory.
I'm triggering with HTTP Post and expecting Function to return status url.

Obviously routing to HttpStart is working based on error logs. I wonder what is the problem.

Error on Azure Data Factory:
Error code 3608
User configuration issue
Call to provided Azure function 'orchestrators/MyOrchestrator' failed with status-'InternalServerError' and message - 'Invoking Azure function failed with HttpStatusCode - InternalServerError.'.

Exception in Application Insight:

```
 Exception while executing function: Functions.MyHttpStart Result: Failure
 Exception: Exception: {'Message': 'Something went wrong while processing your request', 
'ExceptionMessage': 'Forbidden', 'ExceptionType': 
'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException', 'StackTrace': '   at 
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteAsyncInternal[T](RESTCommand`1 
cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext, CancellationToken token)\n   at 
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.CloudTable.CreateIfNotExistsAsync(TableRequestOptions 
requestOptions, OperationContext operationContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at 
DurableTask.AzureStorage.
...
Stack:   File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.8/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 398, in _handle__invocation_request
call_result = await self._run_async_func(
File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.8/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 617, in _run_async_func
return await ExtensionManager.get_async_invocation_wrapper(
File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.8/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/extension.py", line 147, in get_async_invocation_wrapper
result = await function(**args)
File "/home/site/wwwroot/MyHttpStart/__init__.py", line 14, in main
instance_id = await client.start_new(req.route_params["functionName"], None, trigger_message)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/durable_functions/models/DurableOrchestrationClient.py", line 89, in start_new
raise Exception(ex_message)
```

HttpStart code:

```
# This function an HTTP starter function for Durable Functions.
 
import logging
import json
import azure.functions as func
import azure.durable_functions as df

async def main(req: func.HttpRequest, starter: str) -> func.HttpResponse:
    
    trigger_message = req.get_json()
      
    client = df.DurableOrchestrationClient(starter)
    instance_id = await client.start_new(req.route_params["functionName"], None, trigger_message)

    logging.info(f"HTTP Starter: '{instance_id}'.")
   
    return client.create_check_status_response(req, instance_id)
```

Comment: You can refer to [Functions in Azure Data Factory Pipeline debugging Internal Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58970695/functions-in-azure-data-factory-pipeline-debugging-internal-server-error) and [Error code: 3608](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-troubleshoot-guide#error-code-3608)

Comment: I'm still struggling with the problem. Json body content should be valid. I appreciate new ideas where could be issue.